# Add UIImage to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, nsmutablearray, nsdata

I have a problem with a piece of code that should add images to a `NSMutableArray`. For some reason the images are not added (the count of the array stays at 0). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
- (void)incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    _URLString = [notification object];

    for (int i = 0; i < [[self returnLargeUrls] count]; i++) {
        [self getImageFromURL:_URLString];
    }
}
```

And in `getImageFromUrl:`:

```
-(NSData *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {
    UIImage *result;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    [self.pageImages addObject:result];

    NSLog(@"%d", self.pageImages.count);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: wt is [self returnLargeUrls] ??

Comment: NSLog your the result of getImageFromURL make sure it isn't null, then NSLog the results of returnLargeURLs and make sure it isn't empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check would be that you property `pageImages` is not `nil` to begin with.

You can check that like:

```
if(!pageImages)
    NSLog(@"The NSMutableArray pageImages is NIL. Damn... :(");
```

This is most likely your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you `alloc` `init` your `NSMutableArray` first.
2. Make sure your `NSData` is not `nil` after fetching contents from `URL`. `NSLog(@"%@", data);`